# Unable to install Parrot operating system

Tags: linux, debian

How do I install Parrot OS?

While installing Parrot OS (a Linux distro), I extracted the *iso* file from the preferred software i.e: the **Rosa Image Editor**. And I booted from the USB, but when I clicked install, It booted again and started to write all the time:

```
***Quit ^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\Quit^\^\^\^\^\^\^\Quit^\^\^\^\ Framebuffer not available; disabling frontend. Quit ^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\ ^\^\^\^\^\^\^\Quit^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\***
```

I tried the text mode but it didn't work as well. I tried from both BIOS and UEFI but nothing worked.

But the main thing is, I can still boot to the operating system from live mode and everything just works fine.

The most unfortunate part is: I cannot install the distro from live mode and I cannot run the installer as well. So, please help me to fix this problem..

### Background

I am always searching for the best of the OS and since I am poor in my paycheck, I prefer linux operating systems. So, I had tried several linux distributions. Ubuntu and Linux Mint didn't quite work for me and I wanted to use a pentesting operating system. So I tried to install Kali Linux. It was good but resource consuming. So, I decided to install a different pentesting Linux distro; Parrot OS.

Comment: Use imgur to provide some screenshots if you can.

Comment: You say Debian in title and tags and then you speak about Parrot OS...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Parrot OS is actually based on debian.

Comment: @DRP but the parrot version either includes or excludes stuff compared to the Debian source?

Comment: @SolarMike The default list of installed packages would be different; and it may use a different package repository (as Ubuntu does). Otherwise, it should be quite similar. So the tag, at least, should stay.

Comment: @Mukesh Most likely, this is caused by a bug in the Parrot ISO. Try installing an older version, or wait for an update. You may have luck with reporting the problem to them.

Comment: @jpaugh I disagree. When you write about Ubuntu you put ubuntu tag not debian tag, even if ubuntu is based on debian... For me both the title and tags are misleading and will not attract the correct people to solve the problem.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I agree about the title, and submitted an edit. However, we cannot have a tag for [every debian variant](https://wiki.debian.org/Derivatives/Census) out there. Ubuntu is notable enough (and different enough) to merit it's own tag.

Comment: @jpaugh kali-linux is based on debian but has its own tag, same for backtrack, elementaryos, linux-mint, knoppix, raspbian, steam-os, and probably many others...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The point of tags is to help searching, not to catalog and document every piece of software which exists. But, seeing how many [so many questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=parrot+os) involving Parrot OS, I now agree with you: Parrot should have it's own tag, because it's fairly well known.